# Why / How / What is the intermediate step to perform this step?

Tags: factorial, ratio

Here is the expression.

$$\frac { { 10 }^{ n+1 }n! }{ { 10 }^{ n }(n+1)! } =\frac { 10n!\quad { 10 }^{ n } }{ (n+1)n!\quad { 10 }^{ n } }  $$

Can someone help me see the intermediate steps expanded?

Comment: $10^{n+1}=10\cdot 10^n$, and $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$.

Comment: I can see what you are saying. But I cannot see the steps to get there.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean: those *are* the two steps necessary to get from one side of your equation to the other.

Comment: Could you expand on the steps a bit more?

Comment: Factorial by definition is multiplication: $(n+1)!=1*2*3*\dots*n*(n+1)$

Comment: omg, are you serious with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac { { 10 }^{ n+1 }n! }{ { 10 }^{ n }(n+1)! } =\frac { \overset { n+1 }{ \overbrace { 10\cdot 10\cdot ...\cdot 10 } \quad  }  }{ \overset { n }{ \overbrace { 10\cdot 10\cdot ...\cdot 10 } \quad  }  } \cdot \frac { 1\cdot 2\cdot 3...\cdot n }{ 1\cdot 2\cdot 3...\cdot n\cdot \left( n+1 \right)  } =\frac { 10 }{ n+1 } $$